# how to make pathlocationstrategy in angular work on deployed website?

Tags: angular

I have created an application using angular 9 which works perfectly fine locally with `pathlocationstrategy`.
But after creating build using `ng build` and deploying it on the website, it gives 404 page not found error while navigating to different pages or home page.

I am using `pathlocationstrategy` because I don't want `#` in my URL.

can anyone tell how to make it work after deploying it on the server?

Comment: did you use the production flag when building? - not sure if it's relevant but i recall some issues with not including it

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: @JoSSte no, I didn't use production flag. I just used ng build command to create build

Comment: @Eli I am using angular 9

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is because of what actually happens - you request a resource from the server which is located at *mysite.com/some-page*. The server doesn't have such a file "some-page". So it returns error 404 - not found. Your URL path is based on your angular router. So what you should do, you should set up your server to return index.html, doesn't matter what path is received from the browser. You can find more explanations and examples of server configuration in the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: This is lots of fun for folks on shared hosting :)